# Strange behaviour of hierarchical query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a hierarchical query that returns same row (by rowid) several times:

```
select 
    rowid, regexp_substr(col, '[^; ]+', 1, level) data, level
from 
    (select * from table1 where rowid in ('rowid1', 'rowid2'))
connect by 
    regexp_substr(col, '[^; ]+', 1, level) is not null
```

This query returns following result (excerpt):

```
rowid               data    level
AADAxrADkAACic5AAA  val1    1
AADAxrADkAACic5AAA  val2    2
AADAxrADkAACic5AAA  val3    3
AADAxrADkAACic5AAA  val4    4
AADAxrADkAACic5AAA  val5    5
AADAxrADkAACic5AAA  val6    6
```

How can that happen that same row is parent and child of itself?

Also if I want to restrict by rowid which children I want to get:

```
connect by regexp_substr(col, '[^; ]+', 1, level) is not null and prior rowid = rowid
```

Oracle tells me that I have a cycle in my data? That seems reasonable because I have row with same rowid as a parent and child of itself, but how it worked in the previous case (without `and prior rowid = rowid`)?

Comment: What's the original data that you're querying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this can happen if `col` would contain something like `'val1;val2;val3;val4'`. Then each next level would still match the same row, since you're not using any field value of the previous row, but just the level.

SQL-Fiddle proving my suggestion: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10b11/1/0

Oracle tries to detect cycling, but only checks for this if the `prior` keyword is used in the query. This fenomenon is also more or less described on this page: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_advanced_sql_connect_by_loop.htm under the heading 'CONNECT BY without PRIOR':

> **CONNECT BY without PRIOR**
>
> A very popular usage of hierarchical query, documented by Vadim
>   Tropashko in his book SQL Design Patterns, is to generate rows.
>
> ```
> SELECT 
>    SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(DUMMY, '/') 
> FROM 
>    DUAL 
> CONNECT BY 
>    LEVEL<4;
>
> SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(DUMMY,'/')
> --------------------------------
> /X
> /X/X
> /X/X/X
> ```
>
> NOTE:  According to the official documentation, PRIOR is mandatory.
>   Oracle Database SQL Language Reference (11.1) “In a hierarchical
>   query, one expression in the CONNECT BY condition must be qualified by
>   the PRIOR operator”.
>
> The single row of dual is both the parent and the child of itself but
>   no loop is generated. It is a very efficient way to generate rows.

Comment: that is fine, but why when I add another condition to `connect by` clause query fails stating that there is a cycle? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10b11/2

Comment: Yup, that's due to the use of the `prior` keyword. This triggers Oracle to check for cycling. I've updated my answer.

Comment: is it possible to use `prior` in `connect by` but handle cycles by condition in `connect by` clause?

Comment: Yes, using the 'NO_CYCLE' keyword. It seems, though, that this is mainly a debugging feature. Nevertheless, you can use it. More info: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Comment: `nocycle` allows to execute query, but oracle just does not return cycled hierarchy, so I get only one row: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10b11/4. Is is possible to get that cycled hierarchy?

Comment: I'm afraid not. You can do the filtering afterwards by selecting `rowid as currentrowid` and `prior rowid as priorrowid`. You can then put the whole query in a subquery and filter by matching those ids in the parent query. But I think you'll risk winding up with rows that shouldn't be returned.